# Is there a per container based billing for Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

We are planning to use the Azure Blob storage as a cloud storage solution in one of our projects. However, we fail to fully understand the billing mechanism for Blob Storages.

What we need to understand is the billing mechanism for Blob storages based on the below scenario:

**Is the billing only per storage account in a subscription irrespective of the number of containers per storage account? OR can it be further split into per container per storage account?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/

Answer (score 2):

> Is the billing only per storage account in a subscription irrespective
>   of the number of containers per storage account?

That is correct. Primarily you pay for the data stored in these storage accounts.

> OR can it be further split into per container per storage account?

As of today, no. You would need to come up with your own solution to split the charges per container in your storage account.

Comment: Are there any updates on this topic? Is it now possible to create a billing for each container at the same storage account?